# Search in Riak Finds Nothing

Tags: ruby, riak

I'm a newbie to Riak and I'm trying to get Riak Search up and running but so far I'm failing miserably. I've listed the steps I tried below, please advise as to what I'm missing.

1) Create Index:

```
curl -X PUT http://192.168.189.153:10018/search/index/ix1 \
 -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
 -d '{"schema":"_yz_default"}'
```

2) Create and activate index

```
riak-admin bucket-type create citytype '{"props":{"search_index":"ix1"}}'
riak-admin bucket-type activate citytype
```

4) Create using Ruby

```
require 'riak' 
client = Riak::Client.new(:nodes => [
               {:host => "192.168.189.153", :pb_port => 10017},
               {:host => "192.168.189.153", :pb_port => 10027},
               {:host => "192.168.189.153", :pb_port => 10037}
             ])
city = {
   :name => 'Roskilde',
   :countrycode => 'DK',
   :location => '1.2',
   :population => 80000
}   
city_bucket = client.bucket_type('citytype').bucket('byer')
new_city = city_bucket.get_or_new(city[:name])
new_city.data = city
new_city.store(w: 3, dw: 2)
```

5) Retrieve Using Ruby

```
require 'riak'

client = Riak::Client.new(:nodes => [
               {:host => "192.168.189.153", :pb_port => 10017}
             ])

city_bucket = client.bucket_type('citytype').bucket('byer')
fetched = city_bucket.get('Roskilde')
p fetched

results = client.search("ix1", "name:Roskilde")

p results
p results['docs']
```

6) Output

```
ruby search1.rb
#<Riak::RObject {byer,Roskilde} [#<Riak::RContent [application/json]:{"name"=>"Roskilde", "countrycode"=>"DK", "location"=>"1.2", "population"=>80000}>]>
{"max_score"=>0.0, "num_found"=>0, "docs"=>[]}
[]
```

7) Via HTTP

```
http://192.168.189.153:10018/types/citytype/buckets/byer/keys/Roskilde

{"name":"Roskilde","countrycode":"DK","location":"1.2","population":80000}

http://192.168.189.153:10018/search/query/ix1?wt=json&q=name:Roskilde

{"responseHeader":{"status":0,"QTime":10,"params":{"192.168.189.153:10034":"_yz_pn:51 OR _yz_pn:39 OR _yz_pn:36 OR _yz_pn:27 OR _yz_pn:24 OR _yz_pn:12","shards":"192.168.189.153:10014/internal_solr/ix1,192.168.189.153:10024/internal_solr/ix1,192.168.189.153:10034/internal_solr/ix1","q":"name:Roskilde","wt":"json","192.168.189.153:10014":"_yz_pn:64 OR (_yz_pn:61 AND (_yz_fpn:61)) OR _yz_pn:60 OR _yz_pn:57 OR _yz_pn:48 OR _yz_pn:45 OR _yz_pn:33 OR _yz_pn:21 OR _yz_pn:9","192.168.189.153:10024":"_yz_pn:54 OR _yz_pn:42 OR _yz_pn:30 OR _yz_pn:18 OR _yz_pn:15 OR _yz_pn:6 OR _yz_pn:3"}},"response":{"numFound":0,"start":0,"maxScore":0.0,"docs":[]}}
```

8) Error Logs
The `solr.log` file has only explainable errors (cases where I, out of desperation did some *weird* wildcard searching)

The `error.log` file show a number of errors like this, but none from a set of recent new tests:

```
23:15:41.308 [error] Error in process <0.4385.0> on node 'dev1@192.168.189.153' with exit value: {{badmatch,['dev3@192.168.189.153']},[{yz_index,wait_for_index,3,[{file,"src/yz_index.erl"},{line,415}]}]}
```

9) Versions

```
karsten@ubuntu:~/riak$ dev/dev1/bin/riak-admin status | grep riak_kv_version
riak_kv_version : <<"2.0.2-99-g404619c">>
karsten@ubuntu:~/riak$ 

karsten@ubuntu:~/riak$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
karsten@ubuntu:~/riak$
```

Comment: Karsten, I am not a Ruby person so I don't know if your Ruby code is correct however (assuming that it is correct) I would try the following things:

1. Check your error.log and solr.log files. If you have any errors in there those would help diagnose the problem
2. Try your Solr query via curl or your web browser (i.e. http://127.0.0.1:8098/search/query/ix1?wt=json&q=name:Roskilde) to see if it works there

Comment: What version of Riak are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The default schema[0] expects you to append the data type of each field to its name, like `name_s` for string, or `population_i` for integer. Otherwise the field matches the default, which explicitly skips indexing:

```
<dynamicField name="*" type="ignored" />
```

[0] https://raw.githubusercontent.com/basho/yokozuna/develop/priv/default_schema.xml